# $\neg \textbf{CH}$ as restrictive

Tags: logic, set-theory

I'll begin by saying that I don't work in set theory or logic, and am a total novice in these areas.

Nevertheless, for what it's worth, I've tended to think of $\textbf{CH}$ as being restrictive. It places a limit on the size of the continuum and it would seem to place some substantial restrictions on the sorts of sets that could exist. I think of it as implying a more restricted and orderly universe of sets ($\textbf{GCH}$ even more so). That $\textbf{CH}$ holds in $L$ further tends to lead me to view it as restrictive. Conversely, I think of $\neg\textbf{CH}$ as implying a larger, more rich and more diverse universe of sets. However, these are just my rather uneducated musings.

Recently, I've been reading Penelope Maddy's "Believing the Axioms I". In it, she indicated that some younger (at the time of writing) members of the Cabal take the opposite view: $\neg\textbf{CH}$ is restrictive. This really surprised me and now I'm interested in how one might come to such a conclusion. In the paper, Maddy gives one example of an argument in favor of this view. One imagines constructing the iterative hierarchy. She says that at stage $\omega + 2$ one has the reals and a well-ordering of type $\aleph_1$. The issue is whether, at the next stage, one has a one-to-one correspondence between them. Those making this argument claim that it artificially restricts the power set operation not to have such a correspondence.

First question: By well-ordering of type $\aleph_1$ is she just referring to $\omega_1$?

Second question: My next question is just seeking to make sure that I understand this argument correctly. My thinking is that $\neg\textbf{CH}$ implies $\mathfrak{c} > \aleph_1$. This then implies that there is no such bijection. From there, one might argue that this contradicts maximize (such a bijection could exist, so it is arbitrarily limiting to insist that it does not exist).

Third question: If I understand the argument correctly, why couldn't one use this argument and say that it is restrictive to not have a one-to-one correspondence between the reals and some well-ordering of type $\aleph_\alpha$ for $\alpha > 1$ at a later stage? I must be missing something about this argument...

Final Question: Are there any other arguments or any sorts of evidence that one might cite to support the assertion that $\neg\textbf{CH}$ is restrictive?

Edit: I understand that $\textbf{CH}$ is independent of ZFC, so this is more of a philosophical question about how one conceptualizes the effect of adding $\textbf{CH}$ or $\neg\textbf{CH}$ as an axiom (or assuming additional axioms which resolve $\textbf{CH}$ one way or the other). And, in particular, arguments for why one might conceive of $\neg\textbf{CH}$ as being restrictive. Also, by restrictive I generally mean that it goes against the principle or rule of thumb maximize. As I understand it, maximize means something like whatever can be a set, should be a set or if it can exist, it should exist. For example, $V=L$ would commonly be seen to contradict maximize and so be restrictive.

Comment: I will wait for expert voices to chime in, but I think the claim is that 'things should exist as soon as they can exist' as a principle. One _can't_ have the reals until the appropriate stage in the hierarchy, and likewise $\omega_1$, and as soon as possible after — i.e., at the next level of the hierarchy — one 'should' have the mapping between them.

Comment: I am not an expert in this topic, but Joerg Resag claimed that a theory in which the continuum hypothesis is false , is richer. In a german article, he said something like "it seems that the continuum hypothesis should better be false". Of course , this is a matter of a stronger theory than ZFC and how we extend it. Within ZFC, the continuum hypothesis is neither true nor false.

Comment: I suspect the intention is simply that there are many statements arising outside of purely set-theoretic concerns (e.g. in topology, functional analysis, algebra, etc.) that can be proved using CH (a lot of these were formulated and proved in the first half of the 20th century) that later turned out to be independent of CH in the sense that there exists a model of ZF such that the statement is not true. That said, allowing for these models gives more statements that can be proved/disproved, but these types of results tend to be highly technical and primarily of only set-theoretic interest.

Comment: For some reason set theoreticians tend to take the anti-Occamist position that given a choice they prefer the "richer" theory, the more sets the better. What's wrong with "Sets are a necessary evil, let's have just enough of them so we can do ordinary mathematics"?

Comment: @bof presumably for a set theorist, sets aren't a necessary evil, and perhaps for them is also ordinary mathematics:))

Comment: $\omega_1$ is a particular set, the set of all countable ordinals, and it is the least uncountable ordinal. Set theorists usually define (in ZFC) the cardinal of a set as the least ordinal to which it is bijective, and often write $|X|=\omega_1$ for $|X|=\aleph_1.$

Comment: "CH or not" is like "Parallel Postulate or not". You can explore the geometry of $\Bbb R^n$ or you can explore non-Euclidean spaces. A consistent recursive theory that can define arithmetic on $\Bbb N$ must be incomplete (Godel); it makes no sense to me to ask whether a sentence $S$ undecidable from that theory is "preferable" to $\neg S$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Well, of course we can't ask whether $\textbf{CH}$ or $\neg\textbf{CH}$ is preferable in ZFC. However, one might consider adding axioms to ZFC (some of which would decide $\textbf{CH}$, including, for example, just taking $\neg\textbf{CH}$ as an added axiom) and, in that context, one can discuss whether such axioms, or $\textbf{CH}$ itself, are preferable.